# How to find first chance exceptions from output window

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting first chance exceptions in my output window in debug mode.  How do I find where they're coming from? Do I have to put a breakpoint in every catch?

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Some exceptions are raised and swallowed internally by the .NET framework. Unless you set a breakpoint in the .NET source code, you won't be able to analyze them. They will just appear in the output.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to Debug, Exceptions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>), and check the types you're interested in.
This dialog tells the debugger to break whenever an exception is thrown, regardless of whether it's caught.